# Implement ws-notification on axis2

Tags: apache-axis, ws-notification

Do anyone know how to implement WS-Notification on Axis2?
How should I start, or where can i find information about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search gives you some information from 2007. Both:

- [Apache Savan](http://ws.apache.org/savan/)
- [Apache Muse](http://ws.apache.org/muse/docs/2.2.0/manual/index.html)

implement WS-Notification on Axis2. The Muse site includes some sample code, so you could start with the examples.

Comment: However, i have been reading many information about JAX-WS to implement WS-Notification on Axis2. Anyone has experience in these solutions (Apache Savan, Apache Muse, ou JAX-WS)?